# Why is my multi-component UIPickerView crashing?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a simple pickerview with two components, drawing its label data from a small mutablearray and output data from a simple matrix. The purpose of this wheel is to select a value from 0 to 1000, and then spit out the number in a label and the value to the rest of the application's functions.

Some specific info about what I'm doing: (skip down to the last paragraph for the problem)

The left wheel spins a "hundred's" column, and the right wheel spins a "ten's" column, so essentially you're creating one value from two wheels. All I want to do is let the user create a value of 0, 10, 20, 30... 990, 1000 (every ten units up to 1000).The first component is easy to label, but I have two arrays to populate the second component's row's labels. The first array for the second component creates the 00 - 90 label, the second array (for when 1000 is selected) just has a 00 value. So when the user wants to select 1000, the 10 is on the first wheel and 00 on the second. I change the row count for the second wheel component when the first wheel component is at row 10. So now the second component only shows "00". My didSelectRow method uses a matrix for values of 0 - 990 and works great. And I just make a string and convert it to a number for when the user selects 1000 using if statements.

The problem is in the rare circumstance of when the user spins Component 0 to create the value of "1000" (the last row), and if they were start spinning the second component before the first component has a chance to stop spinning (basically spinning in a hurry!), the app crashes. I think it's trying to find a value for a row that doesn't exist. I have other parts of my app that function similarly and they also crash under the same situation. Is there a problem with my approach to changing the number of rows/labels for rows based on the selection of a different component? Or is it something simple in my code?

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the code:

```
 //Baggage Array
        baggageHundredsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            NSString *myBagString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
            [baggageHundredsArray addObject:myBagString];
        }
        [baggageHundredsArray insertObject:@"- " atIndex:0];


        baggageTensArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 10; i <= 90; i = i + 10) {
            NSString *myBagString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d lbs.", i];
            [baggageTensArray addObject:myBagString2];
        }
        [baggageTensArray insertObject:@"00 lbs." atIndex:0];

        baggageTensArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [baggageTensArray2 insertObject:@"00 lbs." atIndex:0];


    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (thePickerView == baggagePicker) {
                NSInteger numComps2 = 0;
                switch (component)
                {
                    case 0:
                        numComps2 = [baggageHundredsArray count];
                        break;
                    case 1:



                    if ([baggagePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] <= 9) 
                    {
                        numComps2 = [baggageTensArray count];
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        numComps2 = [baggageTensArray2 count];
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return numComps2;
        }
}

    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
                viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
              forComponent:(NSInteger)component
               reusingView:(UIView *)view {

        UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;

    if (pickerView == baggagePicker) {
                       if ((pickerLabel == nil) || ([pickerLabel class] != [UILabel class])) {  //newlabel
                           CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 110, 32.0);
                           pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
                           pickerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                           pickerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                           pickerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
                       }            
                       pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


                       switch (component)
                       {
                           case 0:
                               //CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
                               //pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
                               [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
                               [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                               [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:23]];
                               [pickerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
                               [pickerLabel setText:[baggageHundredsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
                               break;

                           case 1:


                               if ([baggagePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] <= 9) {

                                                               [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
                                   [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                                   [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:21]];
                                   [pickerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                                   [pickerLabel setText:[baggageTensArray objectAtIndex:row]];
                               }

                               else 
                               {
                                                               [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
                                   [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                                   [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:21]];
                                   [pickerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                                   [pickerLabel setText:[baggageTensArray2 objectAtIndex:row]];

                               }
                                                   break;   }
                       return pickerLabel;  
                   }


    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

    if (thePickerView == baggagePicker) {

                [baggagePicker reloadAllComponents];

                 NSInteger hundredsWheel = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
                 NSInteger tensWheel  = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
                 //lbs.
                 int column5 [10][10] = {
                 {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
                 {100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190},
                 {200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290},
                 {300,310,320,330,340,350,360,370,380,390},
                 {400,410,420,430,440,450,460,470,480,490},
                 {500,510,520,530,540,550,560,570,580,590},
                 {600,610,620,630,640,650,660,670,680,690},
                 {700,710,720,730,740,750,760,770,780,790},
                 {800,810,820,830,840,850,860,870,880,890},
                 {900,910,920,930,940,950,960,970,980,990},
                 };



                             // Totals Label
                 if (hundredsWheel <= 9) {

                     myBaggageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (column5[hundredsWheel][tensWheel])];
                     baggageWeightLabel.text = myBaggageString;
                     baggageWeightInt = [myBaggageString intValue];

                     baggageWeightFloat = [myBaggageString floatValue];
                     baggageMomentFloat = baggageWeightFloat * 731.10;

                     [self calculateWeight];
                     paxViewBaggageWeightLabel.text = myBaggageString;

                     NSLog(@"value of myBaggageString is %@", myBaggageString);
                     [baggagePicker reloadAllComponents];


                 }

                 if (hundredsWheel == 10){
                     myBaggageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1000"];//, [lastFuelValues objectAtIndex: [weightPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
                     baggageWeightLabel.text = myBaggageString;
                     baggageWeightInt = [myBaggageString intValue];

                     baggageWeightFloat = [myBaggageString floatValue];
                     baggageMomentFloat = baggageWeightFloat * 731.10;

                     [self calculateWeight];
                     paxViewBaggageWeightLabel.text = myBaggageString;
                     [baggagePicker reloadAllComponents];
                 }
```

Comment: Run the app with `⌘Y` and show the debugger output and line where it crashes.

Comment: Any logs? Did you try to debug? What line your code is crashing on?

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I should have included that... I'm still new to programming and even newer to debugging. I'm guessing the first line of the crash log is all I should mention because there's a ton of lines. The first line is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: I think I found a work-around for the time being. I've added blank Strings to my second array after the first object ("00 LBS") so now the second array has the same number of objects as the first array to populate the "Ten's" component. Now when the spinning the second component as the first component is still "settling in" to the last value, it can display blank strings for the split second before the pickerview can reload it's data. At least it doesn't crash now. Does any of this make sense to anyone? Sorry, it's sort of hard to explain. :)Thanks again for taking the time to read and answer!